# jquery filter asp checkboxlist performance

Tags: jquery, asp.net, performance, filter, checkboxlist

I am filtering an asp:checkboxlist of 2000 items and having performance problems. I know its a lot of items, but maybe my code is not ideal? If my code is fine, is there any other ways I could boost performance or am I pretty much pushing it to the limit?
Thank you for your time:

```
  $('#tbSearchUsers').bind('keyup', function (event) {
            var query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

            $('#cblUsers input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                var label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").text().toLowerCase();

                if (label.indexOf(query) > -1) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                    //get parent tr and hide it
                    $(this).parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
  });
```

Comment: Instead of showing all 2000 and then hiding some, why not filter the list of items in code and then only show what you need. I don't think you'll get it more efficient otherwise. 2000 rows of anything is a bad idea, implementing paging might also be a good idea.

Comment: I agree, I have even tried some Jquery libraries with no improvement in performance. The biggest hangup is when keyup fires again while the foreach is still running. If I could exit the previous foreach on keyup and start over it would be nice.

Comment: Could you just do the search on 'click' of a button rather than keyup? Try putting event.Finish(); on line before var query =

Comment: I think the search to click is the way to go as you suggested for a list this large.

Comment: One more note, you could use $(this).closest('tr') to get the parent tr instead of $(this).parent().parent(). Not sure if it's faster than parent().parent()